# Java Swing and Windows XP touch events

Tags: java, swing, windows-xp

I'm trying to find a concrete yes for some assumptions I have about developing a Java Swing app to be run on a Windows tablet device (I believe it'll be running Windows XP).  We have a demo we are writing and we're leveraging previous experience with Java Swing to write the UI and I just want to make sure that touch events in Windows are treated like mouse clicks, is this true?  Does anyone have any direct experience writing Swing apps for Windows tablets?  The target device is [http://www.amazon.com/Promotion-X70EX-3GP-Accessory-Standard/dp/B002MZZX76](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002MZZX76).

Also, wondering if the soft keyboard will automatically be activated when focus is given to a JTextField and other Swing data entry fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We developed an application in Swing which runs well on Windows XP tablets. Yes, touches are treated just like mouse clicks. However, I can only confirm this for basic touch events, e.g. clicking on a button. I can neither confirm nor deny whether they work for more complex gestures.

As for the soft keyboard, I cannot remember whether this works or not. In the end our users ended up using the tablet just like a regular laptop, i.e. with the keyboard not the touch screen. This is mostly due to the amount of text they need to enter in the application.